# How can Google index a website which its html is loaded from a database

Tags: html, database, blogs

I am designing a blog and I want others to be able to log in and create new blog posts.
The contents will be stored in a database and if a person visits the url, its content will be loaded from the database and presented in a template file.
Since the html is not stored in files but rather on a database, will Google be able to index it?

Comment: Hi Lucretius, the basic answer to your question is that Google does a lot of processing, caching, and most likely a ton of very complicated methods by which, if they believe that your site is worth indexing (even as a single page, database loaded type of site). There are things you can do to give Google SEO a better chance (for example: they have Ad Words and site verification that would likely help), but Google can cache your site regardless.

Comment: See also the fact that this is how a vast majority of modern websites work (for example: This site)

Answer (score 0):

Clients on the web, be they browsers, search engines, or anything else have no way of knowing and no reason to care what a web server does (be it read a static file, generate HTML by combining data in a database with a template, generate random data with a Markov chain text generator or anything else) to determine what content to return when it is asked for the resource associated with a URL.

Comment: But I thought google crawls a website through the files in the web server

Comment: So it gets the files through the links in the website?

Comment: Google crawls URLs. It can’t crawl the server’s hard disk directly. If it could then anyone could and that would be an enormous security problem.